# building the RIBBON dynamically: e.OriginalSource is no longer of type: RibbonButton

Tags: command, ribbon

I want to build my RIBBON-buttons dynamically. Every click on a RIBBON-button must result in opening an usercontrol. The command attached to the button is the same for all buttons.
In the executed-procedure I need the RibbonButton that activated the action.

the "executed" Command looks like this:

```
    private void ExecTmp(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RibbonButton btn = e.OriginalSource as RibbonButton;
        Console.WriteLine("===========e.Orig: " + e.OriginalSource.ToString());
        // do something with 'btn'   
     }
```

Now, the strange thing is that it works, as long as focus does not leave the Ribbon.
If I enter a userControl on a tab (a textBlock or something) and then click on a ribbonButton again, I no longer have access to the RibbonButton. I can see on my console, that the reason for this is that e.originalSource is no longer a RibbonButton but a textBox. Output on my console looks like this:

```
===========e.Orig: Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonButton
===========e.Orig: System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: 0
===========e.Orig: System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: 0
===========e.Orig: System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: 0
```

In the debugger I can see that if I open a tabControl, click on a combobox in the tabControl and then on the RibbonButton, e.Source points to the opened tabControl and e.OriginalSource points to the ComboBox. Isn't this strange?

Can somebody explain this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for this question :) But anyway, hope my answer will be useful for someone else.

Set `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"` for Ribbon control. This will cause `e.OriginalSource` to contain `RibbonButton`, not `TextBox`.